# Android CardView setting/hiding Icons when clicked on Image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a Horizontal CardView and a ViewHolder using RecyclerView.ViewHolder. 
I want to set an extra image (selected icon) when clicked on an image in cardView.
In my card view I have 7 pictures. When I click on first picture, selected icon is setted correct. But this icon is also setted on 6th picture. 
If I click on 2th picture in card view, then the icon is automatically setted on 7th picture.

What is wrong here? 
How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks.

```
public class CVAreaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CVAreaAdapter.AreaViewHolder> {

    List<Area> areaList;
    Activity activity;
    static AreaViewHolder prevHolder = null;

    public CVAreaAdapter(List<Area> areaList, Activity activity){
        this.areaList = areaList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public static class AreaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView areaName;
        ImageView areaPhoto;
        ImageView selectedIcon;
        String currentItemName;
        int areaId;
        boolean iconVisible = false;

        AreaViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            areaName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_area_name);
            areaPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_area_photo);
            selectedIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_selected_icon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public AreaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.area_cv_item_horizontal, viewGroup, false);
        final AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder = new AreaViewHolder(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                // item clicked
                Toast.makeText(activity, "selected areaName: "
                        + areaViewHolder.currentItemName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateIcon(areaViewHolder);
            }
        });
        return areaViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder, int i) {
        areaViewHolder.areaName.setText(areaList.get(i).getName());
        areaViewHolder.areaPhoto.setImageResource(areaList.get(i).getImageId());
        areaViewHolder.currentItemName = (areaList.get(i).getName());
        areaViewHolder.areaId = (areaList.get(i).getId());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return areaList.size();
    }


    public void updateIcon(AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder){
                if(getPrevHolder() != null) {
                    // remove selected icon from previous picture
                    hideIcon(getPrevHolder());
                }
                setIcon(areaViewHolder);
    }
    private void setIcon(AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder){

        if(!areaViewHolder.iconVisible ) {
            showIcon(areaViewHolder);
        } else{
            hideIcon(areaViewHolder);
        }
        setPrevHolder(areaViewHolder);
    }

    public void hideIcon(AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder){
        areaViewHolder.selectedIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        areaViewHolder.iconVisible = false;
    }

    public void showIcon(AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder){
        areaViewHolder.iconVisible = true;
        areaViewHolder.selectedIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public void setPrevHolder(AreaViewHolder areaViewHolder){
        this.prevHolder = areaViewHolder;
    }

    public AreaViewHolder getPrevHolder(){
        return this.prevHolder;
    }


}
```

Comment: There's nothing to talk about without any code.

Comment: I have added now my code.

Comment: I have also tried without static classes without success :(